# C++ & FLTK: load PNG image from file

Tags: c++, image, fltk

I'm trying to load image, but I get this error:

> LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall
>   Fl_PNG_Image::Fl_PNG_Image(char const *)" (??0Fl_PNG_Image@@QAE@PBD@Z)
>   referenced in function _main

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_PNG_Image.H>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Fl_Window *window = new Fl_Window(1024, 768);

    Fl_PNG_Image *img = new Fl_PNG_Image("С:/src/image.png");
    img->draw(0, 0);

    window->end();
    window->show(argc, argv);

    return Fl::run();
}
```

P.S. I added FLTK Header files and libs to the VS. Additional dependencies also include fltk.lib and Comctl32.lib. Program is working without image initialization.

Comment: Did you add `fltkimages.lib`? The documentation indicates that is necessary: http://www.fltk.org/documentation.php/doc-1.1/Fl_PNG_Image.html

Comment: [the problem is solved]

As far as I understand, this documentation: http://www.fltk.org/documentation.php/doc-1.1/Fl_PNG_Image.htmll  for FLTK v1.1. I use v1.3 and it have separate documentation: http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/classFl__PNG__Image.html  where is no mention about Additional Libraries.

After trying to add flktimages.lib, I got 10 new unresolved external symbol errors. However old error disappeared. After several attempts, it became clear that also needed fltkpng.lib and fltkzlib.lib.

Comment: You will also need fltkjpeg.lib if you add jpg files.

Answer (score 1):

For using image features of FLTK you have to link your program with "fltk_image" library (in addition to usual "fltk"). Seems like the problem is you did not.